# Bot de discord.py no printea al usuario mencionado

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

Estoy haciendo un bot para discord y quería hacer que "realice una acción", como el de abajo que le dice *tequiero* a la persona que se menciona post comando, pero cuando quiero sacar la mención para que se printee me dice que el objeto `str` no es calleable.

```
import discord 
from discord.ext import commands
import datetime
import os 


intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True 

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')

@bot.command()
async def tqm(ctx, user):
    user = ctx.message.author.mention()
    await ctx.send("{0.mention}".format(user)+" , Te quiero bro! UwU")
```

Comment: Quita los parentesis de `ctx.message.author.mention()` . El atributo mention NO es una función para obtener la mención, es la mención en si

Comment: Además, te surgirá un error más adelante. Un str que representa la mención del usuario NO tiene el atributo mention. Así que te recomiendo cambiar esto `"{0.mention}".format(user)` por esto `"{0}".format(user)`

Comment: ¿Sabes que hay una palabra en castellano para el verbo "to print"? Se dice "imprimir". El lenguaje es importante, especialmente en una entrevista de trabajo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

era innecesario hacer una variable para callear al user, con el simple hecho de pasarle el dato en el comando bastaba

```
@bot.command()
async def tqmbro(ctx, user):
    await ctx.send("{0}".format(user)+" , Te quiero bro! UwU")
```

Comment: Yo tendría en cuenta el consejo de Candid Moe sobre el lenguaje. En español callear sería llamar.